# Do you backup a single switch or each switch on a extreme summit to tftp server?

Tags: networking, switch

I want a backup of my switching environment, so I looked up how to backup a system configuration file.I just uploaded a configuration file to my Tftp server and it completed just fine. I was wondering if I need a copy of each .cfg file, for each switch or will one work for all? Here is a output from the version command.

```
Slot-1 TULEDGE51.8 # show version
Slot-1      : 800324-00-03 1052G-01440 Rev 3.0 BootROM: 2.0.1.0    IMG: 12.5.3.9
Slot-2      : 800324-00-03 1052G-01239 Rev 3.0 BootROM: 2.0.1.0    IMG: 12.5.3.9
Slot-3      : 800324-00-03 1052G-01438 Rev 3.0 BootROM: 2.0.1.0    IMG: 12.5.3.9
Slot-4      : 800324-00-03 1052G-01238 Rev 3.0 BootROM: 2.0.1.0    IMG: 12.5.3.9
Slot-5      : 800324-00-03 1052G-01439 Rev 3.0 BootROM: 2.0.1.0    IMG: 12.5.3.9
Slot-6      :
Slot-7      :
Slot-8      :
SS-V80-B-1  : 800385-00-02 1049G-00237 Rev 2.0
SS-V80-B-2  : 800385-00-02 1049G-00238 Rev 2.0
SS-V80-B-3  : 800385-00-02 1049G-00345 Rev 2.0
SS-V80-B-4  : 800385-00-02 1049G-00239 Rev 2.0
SS-V80-B-5  : 800385-00-02 1049G-00324 Rev 2.0

Image   : ExtremeXOS version 12.5.3.9 v1253b9 by release-manager
          on Tue Apr 26 20:36:04 PDT 2011
BootROM : 2.0.1.0
Diagnostics : 2.10
```

Comment: I thought summits were workgroup/edge switches and not chassis-based products. I thought those were alpines and black diamonds (but I'm not in an extreme shop any more). What's the exact model of this switch/chassis?

Comment: Yes their 5-x460 edge switches, just opened their web interface, clicked save config- then updated fine, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question.  If your switches have different configurations, then you would need a backup from each one to make sure that you can restore each one's own individual configuration.  If they all have the exact same configuration, then you would be able to use just one configuration.

Comment: My XOS is rusty but this is either a chassis or a very large stack, which might change the answer.